# How to get a value from a dynamic form?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I am using .NET Core with razor pages and I have a model as a list of object as below. Can anyone tell me how to do it? I searched many forums, seems only using controller can do it.

Here is the razor cshtml form I'm using:

```
 <form id="form" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post"  >
        <h4>Performance Rating</h4>
        <div>
            <p>
                <mark>
                    @Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(24)).ContentText
                </mark>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="contentTbl" class="display nowrap table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">
                            @Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(25)).ContentText
                        </th>
                        <th style="font-size:xx-small" width="5%">(a)<br /> @Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(26)).ContentText</th>
                        <th style="font-size:xx-small" width="5%">(b) <br />@Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(27)).ContentText</th>
                        <th style="font-size:xx-small" width="5%">(c)=(a)X(b)<br />@Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(28)).ContentText</th>
                        <th>@Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(29)).ContentText</th>
                        <th width="5%">@Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(30)).ContentText</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{ var j = 0; }
                    @{ var QuestionId = 0;}

                    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.QuesAns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        j = k + 1;
                        QuestionId = Model.QuesAns[k].QuestionId;
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>@j. @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].TitleText)</h5>
                                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].ContentText)</p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="QuestionId_@j" , id="QuestionId_@j" value="@QuestionId" />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <lable id="Weighting_@j">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].Weighting)</lable>%
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <select class="form-control p-0" name="Weighting_@j" id="Weighting_@j" asp-for="@Model.QuesAns[k].Weighting">
                                    <option value="0"></option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                            <td align="center"><lable id="WeightingMarks_@j"></lable></td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="Comment_@j" id="Comment_@j" asp-for="@Model.QuesAns[k].Answer" ></textarea>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                (@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].AttachNum))
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" class="ClickAttach"><span class="k-icon k-i-attachment-45"></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    <tr style="background-color:burlywood">
                        <td align="right">
                            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.QuesAns.Count" name="TotalQues" id="TotalQues" />
                            <b>
                                @Model.CommonContents.Find(x => x.ContentId.Equals(31)).ContentText
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>100%</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><label id="TotalWeightingMarks"></label></td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="formAction" name="formAction" style="display:none">
         <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Confirmed" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" />
            </div>



        </div>
    </form>
```

javascript part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $('#formAction').val("submit");
        }); });
```

the coding page like this

```
[BindProperty]
    public List<VAppraisalQuestionAnswer> qa { set; get; }
 public IActionResult OnPost(string formAction)
    {
        //i want to get value from the from
        var abc = qa;  // qa is return count= 0
        return Page();
    }
```

Here is the model

```
 public class VAppraisalQuestionAnswer
{



    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StaffCode { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DeptCode { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string AppraisalPeriodCode { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(int.MaxValue)]
    public string TitleText { get; set; }
    [StringLength(int.MaxValue)]
    public string ContentText { get; set; }
    public int Weighting { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int AttachNum { get; set; }
    public int DspOrd { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the solution. All I need to do is add `IFormCollection` to the `OnPostAsync`, then `IFormCollection` returns the array value.

like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormCollection Form)        {
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind a simple type list object, the name attribute in the input text should in this format: `[index].property`. The index must start from `0` and be continuous. Change the table body like below:

```
<tbody>
    @{ var j = 0; }
    @{ var QuestionId = 0;}

    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.QuesAns.Count; k++)
    {
        j = k + 1;
        QuestionId = Model.QuesAns[k].QuestionId;
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h5>@j. @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].TitleText)</h5>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].ContentText)</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@k].QuestionId" , id="QuestionId_@j" value="@QuestionId" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <lable id="Weighting_@j">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].Weighting)</lable>%
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select class="form-control p-0" name="[@k].Weighting" id="Weighting_@j" asp-for="@Model.QuesAns[k].Weighting">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td align="center"><lable id="WeightingMarks_@j"></lable></td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="[@k].Comment" id="Comment_@j" asp-for="@Model.QuesAns[k].Answer"></textarea>

            </td>
            <td>
                (@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Model.QuesAns[k].AttachNum))
                <a href="#" target="_blank" class="ClickAttach"><span class="k-icon k-i-attachment-45"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr style="background-color:burlywood">
        <td align="right">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.QuesAns.Count" name="TotalQues" id="TotalQues" />

        </td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><label id="TotalWeightingMarks"></label></td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: hi mj1313, thanks for answering my question, i think i find the way to get dynamic form post value, please see below my post. Thanks.